# How do I use different pricing rules for different products?

Tags: javascript

I want to set different pricing rules for different products eg. the D91 should have a fixed total cost irrespective of the quantity while others are usual (price * quantity). So, in the code, how do I set total cost for D91 to be the same irrespective of quantity and total cost for the others (price * quantity)?

```
shoppingCart.totalCart = function() { // return total cost
var totalCostinitial=0;
var totalCostencorr=0;
var totalCostd91=0;
var totalCostdealing=0;
for (var i in this.cart) {
    if (this.cart[i].name === "D91") {
        totalCostd91 = this.cart[i].price;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Full EnCorr Pack" || this.cart[i].name === "EnCorr Reporting") {
        totalCostotherdev = this.cart[i].price;
    }/*
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Suspending Funds" || this.cart[i].name === "Unsuspending Funds") {
        totalCost = Math.ceil(this.cart[i].count/10) * 37.75;
    }*/
    if(this.cart[i].name === "One whole sentence change" || this.cart[i].name === "One word within a sentence" || this.cart[i].name === "Header/Footer amendments to Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "Adding Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "Removing Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "LetterType level configuration changes i.e. set letter to deferred printing" || this.cart[i].name === "Adding existing signature to a single template" || this.cart[i].name === "Add a copy letter" || this.cart[i].name === "Deleting lettertypes" || this.cart[i].name === "New/Amendments to Paragraph in existing correspondence" || this.cart[i].name === "New/Amendments to letter variables (prompts both user and automatic)" || this.cart[i].name === "Creation of a single new signature" || this.cart[i].name === "New Letter" || this.cart[i].name === "New Variable" || this.cart[i].name === "New Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "New Template" !== (this.cart[i].name === "Full EnCorr Pack" || this.cart[i].name === "EnCorr Reporting")) {
        var totalCostencorrinitial=0
        totalCostencorr += this.cart[i].price * this.cart[i].count;
    }/*
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing - Internal" || this.cart[i].name === "RSF Add/Update Increments - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/600 * 571.20;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "One whole sentence change" || this.cart[i].name === "One word within a sentence" || this.cart[i].name === "Header/Footer amendments to Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "Adding Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "Removing Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "LetterType level configuration changes i.e. set letter to deferred printing" || this.cart[i].name === "Adding existing signature to a single template" || this.cart[i].name === "Add a copy letter" || this.cart[i].name === "Deleting lettertypes" || this.cart[i].name === "New/Amendments to Paragraph in existing correspondence" || this.cart[i].name === "New/Amendments to letter variables (prompts both user and automatic)" || this.cart[i].name === "Creation of a single new signature" || this.cart[i].name === "New Letter" || this.cart[i].name === "New Variable" || this.cart[i].name === "New Enclosures" || this.cart[i].name === "New Template" || this.cart[i].name === "Full EnCorr Pack" || this.cart[i].name === "EnCorr Reporting") {
        totalCost += this.cart[i].price * this.cart[i].count;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing - External" || this.cart[i].name === "RSF Add/Update Increments - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/600 * 672.00;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing Cancellation - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/4000 * 571.20;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing Cancellation - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/4000 * 672.00;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing Settlement - Internal" || this.cart[i].name === "RSF QC - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/2500 * 571.20;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing Settlement - External" || this.cart[i].name === "RSF QC - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/2500 * 672.00;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing Cash Receipting - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/6000 * 571.20;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Dealing Cash Receipting - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/6000 * 672.00;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "New Client Setup - Internal" || "Unitholder Coverall Mandate Setup - Internal" || this.cart[i].name === "Fund Setup (Standing Data) - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/1000 * 571.20;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "New Client Setup - External" || "Unitholder Coverall Mandate Setup - External" || this.cart[i].name === "Fund Setup (Standing Data) - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/1000 * 672.00;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Client Maintenance Updates - Internal" || this.cart[i].name === "Unitholder Maintenance Updates - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/2000 * 571.20;;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Client Maintenance Updates - External" || this.cart[i].name === "Unitholder Maintenance Updates - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/2000 * 672.00;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "New Unitholder Setup - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/1500 * 571.20;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "New Unitholder Setup - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/1500 * 672.00;
    }
    if(this.cart[i].name === "Pricing Maintenance - Internal") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/3000 * 571.20;
    }
    this.cart[i].name === "Pricing Maintenance - External") {
        totalCost = this.cart[i].count/3000 * 672.00;
    }*/
    totalCost = totalCostinitial + totalCostotherdev + totalCostencorr
}
return totalCost.toFixed(2);
}

shoppingCart.listCart = function() { // array of items
var cartCopy = [];
for (var i in this.cart) {
    var item = this.cart[i];
    var itemCopy = {};
    for (var p in item) {
        itemCopy[p] = item[p];
    }
    itemCopy.total = (item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
    cartCopy.push(itemCopy);
}
return cartCopy;
}
```

Please help! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: I read a question. Just because there  is no "How do I do that?" it is still a question. PS JS tests for equality does not work the way you use it in the commented statements. You need `if (name==="x" || name ==="y")` instead of `if (name==="x" || "y")`

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement that

Comment: You need some kind of object array: `var pricing = { "d91": { discount:0, fullprice:true, quantumrebate:1}, "Dealing Cancellation - External": { discount:0, quantumrebate:4000 } }`

Comment: Also, why doesn't the function work when I use this.cart[i].count?

Comment: You did not post enough code for that question to be answered

Comment: Can you have multiple carts ? `this.cart[i].count` seems to iterate over a series of carts and apply count on them. Did you type the colons? `.count()` ?